# chatterbot is not gettinf install please help me

Tags: python, installation, jupyter-lab, chatterbot

what's wrong I am not able to install chatterbot

I want to install chatterbot

```
  Using cached PyYAML-5.1.2.tar.gz (265 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [37 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mix1g2t8\pyyaml_a2aa2fc4de6c4b7e993150e2f77bdae6\setup.py", line 291, in <module>
          setup(
        File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 963, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 321, in run
          self.find_sources()
        File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 329, in find_sources
          mm.run()
        File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 550, in run
          self.add_defaults()
        File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 588, in add_defaults
          sdist.add_defaults(self)
        File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\sdist.py", line 102, in add_defaults
          super().add_defaults()
        File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\sdist.py", line 251, in add_defaults
          self._add_defaults_ext()
        File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\sdist.py", line 336, in _add_defaults_ext
          self.filelist.extend(build_ext.get_source_files())
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mix1g2t8\pyyaml_a2aa2fc4de6c4b7e993150e2f77bdae6\setup.py", line 199, in get_source_files
          self.cython_sources(ext.sources, ext)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 107, in __getattr__
          raise AttributeError(attr)
      AttributeError: cython_sources
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you need download them and install them i am using python 3.8 64 bit and trying to install chatterbot using the command: pip install chatterbot.